# highcharts how to divide axis into 2

Tags: highcharts

I have 2 axis both on the same side, they are both taking up the entire axis and so the labels are overlapping and the graphs are crossing.  What I'd like is to allocate 2/3 of the the space on top for the first series and 1/3 for the 2nd, so graphically looks like

```
|-
|
|
|
|
|-
|
|
|-
```

The values could be anything for either series, point is they only have a certain amount of the graph to work with.  Any way to achieve this?

```
yAxis: [
        {
            offset: -6,
            title: {
                text: 'two',
                align: 'high',
                rotation: 0,    
                offset: 8,
                y: -6,
                x: 20,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '7px'
                }
            },


            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                color: 'orange',
                width: 1,
                zIndex: 5,
                dashStyle: 'Solid'
            }],

            opposite: true,
            //minorGridLineColor: 'green',
            gridLineColor: 'black'
        }, 

        {
            offset: -6,
            title: {
                text: 'one',
                align: 'high',
                rotation: 0,    
                offset: 8,
                y: -6,
                x: 20,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '7px'
                }
            },


            plotLines: [ {
                value: 0,
                color: 'orange',
                width: 1,
                zIndex: 5,
                dashStyle: 'Solid'
            }],

            opposite: true,
            gridLineColor: 'black'
        }
```

Comment: do you have 2 xAxis or 2 yAxis. what do you mean by allocation of space. the graphical representation you mentioned, sorry i was not able to understand it. can you please post a image if possible.

Comment: Recreate your example on the jsfiddle.net, please

Comment: want to divide y axis into 2 portions

Comment: by xAxis (as separator between yAxis) or using two yAxis panes? Attach any mockup / demo or something

Comment: I attached the code for 2 axis but not sure how helpful it is

Comment: Attach image how it should look like.